# Calender Extender in Ajax toolkit not working properly in ASP.NET Content Page

Tags: asp.net, ajax, calendar

I am implementing a project in asp.net where I am using calender extender of Ajax toolkit.
The calender extender is used in the content page. But it is not correctly showing the calender. The calender is misplaced from the 'textbox' which owns the calender extender.

Comment: @RijuMahna i am not using javascript for this.

Comment: you can position it using CSS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just write the style for the Calendar Extender in a seperate CSS class,

Then assign it to the Calendar Extender.

```
<asp:CalendarExtender   ID="CalendarExtender1"  runat="server"  TargetControlID="TextBox1"    CssClass="CalendarCSS"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this ..

```
<asp:TextBox   ID="TextBox1"  runat="server"/>

<asp:CalendarExtender   ID="CalendarExtender1"  runat="server"  TargetControlID="TextBox1"    CssClass="CalendarCSS"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the **TargetControlID** of the Calendar Extender is equal to the TextBoxID and then you include the **PopupPosition** property.

For example:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<cc1:CalendarExtender ID="CalendarExtender1" runat="server" TargetControlID="TextBox1" PopupPosition="Right"></cc1:CalendarExtender>
```

I hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to solve this issue is just add an ajax assembly to your page, on the top:

```
<%@ Register assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" tagprefix="ajaxToolkit" %>
```

And don't forget to add the tagprefix on the calender extender as "ajaxToolkit".

ex:

```
<ajaxToolkit:CalendarExtender ID="txtPostingDate_CalendarExtender"
runat="server" Enabled="True" TargetControlID="txtPostingDate"
Format="MM/dd/yyyy">
                                            </ajaxToolkit:CalendarExtender>
```